# Remove all Docker images without containers or child images, even if they're tagged

Tags: docker

I want to clean up all of my Docker images that aren't being used, directly or indirectly, by my current containers. Docker provides the `docker image prune` command for this, but I can't get it to remove exactly what I want. If I use that command without `-a`, it removes too little: it leaves behind all tagged images, even if no container uses them. If I use that command with `-a`, it removes too much: it removes images that are parents of images that aren't being removed. Here's a table explaining the problem:

| Used by container | Has child image | Has tag | Removed without -a | Removed with -a | I want to remove |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes/No | Yes/No | No | No | No |
| No | Yes | Yes/No | No | Yes | No |
| No | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |
| No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |

Is there some other flag for this command (such as something with `--filter`), or some other command or sequence of commands, that lets me remove just what I want to remove?

**EDIT**: [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) points out in the comments that the images I'm referring to are merely being untagged, not removed entirely. Given that, here's an updated phrasing of the question: How can I make `docker image prune -a` not untag images that it's not actually going to remove?

Comment: I generally disrecommend `docker images -a` (because it can be confusing) but if you look very carefully you should see that Docker isn’t _actually_ removing parent images, just their tag, in the `prune -a` case.  “Has child image” is hard to determine programmatically.

Comment: @DavidMaze Interesting. Given that, I suppose my actual question is "How do I make it not remove the tag in those cases?"

Answer (score 2):

I often wondered the same thing, so I came up with this solution:

```
# create unique array of image ids (including all descendants) used by running containers
get_active_image_history()
{
    for image_name in $(docker ps --format={{.Image}})
    do
        docker history -q $image_name
    done | sort -u
}

# iterate over each image id in your system, and output the ids that should be deleted
# conceptually similar to an intersection of two arrays
get_unused_image_ids()
{
    image_history=$(get_active_image_history)
    for image_id in $(docker image ls -q)
    do
        if [[ ! "${image_history[@]}" =~ "${image_id}" ]]; then
            echo "$image_id"
        fi
    done  | sort -u
}

docker_clean()
{
    image_ids=$(get_unused_image_ids)
    if [ -z "$image_ids" ]; then
        >&2 echo "Error: no unused images found"
        return 1
    fi

    if [[ "$1" = "-y" ]]; then
        echo y | docker container prune > /dev/null
        docker image rm $(get_unused_image_ids)
        return 0
    fi

    echo -e "Warning! this will remove all stopped containers, and the following images:\n"
    image_ids=$(get_unused_image_ids)
    echo "REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE"
    docker image ls | grep "$image_ids"
    echo
    read -p "Continue (y/n)?" cont
    if [ "$cont" = "y" ]; then
        echo y | docker container prune > /dev/null
        docker image rm $image_ids
    else
        echo "aborting..."
    fi
}
```

No very elegant, but it works well enough for use in *development*.  You can pass a `-y` flag to silence the warning prompt.

There are several cases that I came across where the prompt incorrectly showed an image that was currently used, and attempted to remove it, but was then caught by
the docker daemon which results in misleading noise similar to this:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete <image id> (must be forced) -
image is being used by stopped container <container id>
```

In all cases, only the *correct* images were removed, but this might vary depending on your system. YMMV

**TLDR; not production safe**

Answer (score -1):

```sh
docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h"
```

This is something that I use, hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: How is this any different than `docker image prune`, which doesn't do what I want?

Comment: docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h" 

This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Which are not being used from past 24hours. you can reduce it.
You can even use additional filter label as well.

Comment: I have changed my answer accordingly. Try and let me know if this works.